# update directive element values with templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, directive, controllers

**template html:**

i have a  element into  the template **seats.tpl.html** file, like this:

```
<select  id="guest_table">
    <option tables="emptySeats"
            ng-repeat="table in emptySeats" value="{{table.tableId}}">{{table.tableNumber}}</option>
</select>
```

**controller**

into controller i call a factory to get the values from dbase, actually i load the result into the  **$scope.emptySeats** array which into template with ng-repeat create the :

```
factP3_GetEmptyChairs.getEmptyChairs({'data': {'id': 58}})
                .then(function (result) {
                    **$scope.emptySeats = result.data;**
                    $log.info("Empty chairs list loaded.");
                },
                function (result) {
                    $('.loading').hide();
                    $log.error("Error: we could not get Empty seats list.");
                });
```

**directive:**

into my directive i use parameter **templateUrl** to call the template file in order to load the , again so far so good, the select loads with values.

```
.directive('emptySeats',function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: true,
            scope:{tables :'='},
            templateUrl: function(){
                return 'assets/modules/part3/templates/emptySeats.tpl.html';
            },

            link:function(scope, element, attrs) {                                                                           
                //bind change on element
                element.bind('change', function() {
                    alert("table changed");
                });

            }
        }
```

My problem is that whenever i change the **$scope.emptySeats** array values i need to automatically update the  values, that does not happen with my current code.

**something i miss into the directive i think , is it compile, is it observe, is it ngmodel, can anyone help?**

**UPDATED:**
**i call a function to get new data from db and load them to select element**

```
 $scope.onClickHall = function (hall) {
    var tmp = [];
    //call service to load empty Seats
    factP3_GetEmptyChairs.getEmptyChairs({'data': {'id': $scope.currentHall}})
        .then(function (result) {
            //$scope.emptySeats = result.data;
```

**A: If i use $apply here,i get : Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress**

```
        $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.emptySeats = result.data;;
            });
            tmp = result.data; //i use a temp array to pass it on timeout

            $log.info("Empty chairs list loaded.");
        },
        function (result) {
            $('.loading').hide();
            $log.error("Error: we could not get Empty seats list.");
        });
```

**B. if i use $timeout function and try to change the data , nothing happens**

```
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.emptySeats = tmp;
        });
    }, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use template files to enhance the capabilities of bootstrap popovers, tooltips, etc. There are two types of templates can be used to serve for the purpose.

Inline templates - Template code will define in the same HTML file and it will call by an angular directive.
Example:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
   <h1>Hi</h1>
</script>
```

The template contents can be defined in an external file and can be called as an ajax request. In this approach you may need to use the ajax call similar to `$http.get(templateURL)`

The direcive definition should be define as below in order to corerctly attached the template. Note that the usage of `$compile` in order to correctly integrate the contents. This will ensure that the contents will be correctly integrated to your directive contents.

Find below an example.

```
angular.module('myApp')
      .directive('myPopover', function () {
        var getTemplate = function () {
            var template = '';
                template = $templateCache.get("myTemplate.html");
            }
            return template;
        };

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        text: '@myPopover'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var popOverContent = getTemplate();
            popOverContent = $compile("<div>" + popOverContent+"</div>")(scope);

            var options = {
                //title       : title,
                content     : popOverContent,
                placement   : "right",
                html        : true,
                date        : scope.date,
                trigger     : "hover"
            };
            $(element).popover(options);
      }
    };
  });
```

This is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8tB6bA?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Since your `$http` call is async, you need to call [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to trigger `$digest` cycle to re-render the directive view:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
   $scope.emptySeats = result.data;
});
```

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries).

Comment: hello, i tried $scope.$apply and i updated my question